# How to display photo locations over the top of the photo?

Tags: gps, photos, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a friend with a Note 4 who wants to display the location information of his pictures overlaid on top of the image itself (rather than go to Details to view the extra info). He saw another person do this on a S3. Couldn't see anything obvious to do it on his phone. He basically wants it to quickly go through photos and remember where they were taken, rather than going into individual photos 1 by 1.

Apologies, I'm not too familiar with Android, so not sure if I'm describing this correctly.

In particular we're looking for something that generally looks like this overlay https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9B9O.jpg (found from [Can't view Location (textual desciption) information in Windows when opening picture taken with Camera app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91524/cant-view-location-textual-desciption-information-in-windows-when-opening-pic) )